# Jquery .load php access not allowed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i have a problem with my code, its simple.

Archive: index.php

```
<PHP
define( "MYCODE", TRUE );
include('update.php');
?>
```

Archive: update.php

```
<?PHP
if ( !defined("MYCODE") )
    die( "Error" );
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
    {
        var r = (-0.5)+(Math.random()*(1000.99));
        $('#some-div').load('ajax.php');
    }, 60000);
});
</script>
<div id="some-div"></div>
```

Archive: ajax.php

```
<?PHP
if ( !defined("MYCODE") )
    die( "Error" );

$sql=mysql_query....

?>
```

how to allow the script to have access to file ajax.php?

direct access not allowed, but the script same error.

Comment: Check your files permissions and also your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

MYCODE will not be defined in your ajax call because the execution of index.php has finished by the time you load ajax.php.

Answer (score 0):

your ajax.php file is requested as another call to your server - basically it is launch as standalone file, so there is no way where MYCODE constant is initiated

Answer (score 0):

Best to creat a session so all files can share the session variable.